# rxjava observable get value without blocking

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

Consider the following pseudo code

```
Map<Event, Map<Long, Model>> events = Observable
    .from(events())
    .map(event -> Pair.of(event, bucket
            .async()
            .get(event)
            .map(this::toMap)
    ))
    .map(pair -> Pair.of(pair.getKey(),
            pair.getValue().toBlocking().singleOrDefault(null))) // this blocks thread
    .filter(pair -> pair.getValue() != null)
    .toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue)
    .toBlocking()
    .single();
```

Is there a way how I can get value from `Obesrvable<Map<Long, Model>>` (see commented part of the code)  without calling `toBlocking()` cause it is basically blocks thread.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Replace `.map(...)` with `.flatMap(pair -> pair.getValue().map(value -> Pair.of(pair.getKey(), value)))`. This flattens the async request for the value and then maps the key back onto it.

Comment: i get an error during compile time saying cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Event,Map<Long,Model>>

Comment: Likely because of the inner generics. If you specify the exact type for `Pair.<K,V>of` or the `<Pair<K,V>>flatmap` call it should be able to correctly deduce all the types.

Comment: Kiskae, could you please provide the whole code, i don't really understand what to change

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge, subscribeOn and observeOn to achieve the non blocking behavior you want:

```
private class Model {
}

private class Event {

    private Long id;
    private Model model;

    public Event(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Event(Long id, Model model) {
        this.id = id;
        this.model = model;
    }
}

private class Async {
    public Observable<Event> get(Event event) {
        return Observable.just(new Event(1L, new Model())).observeOn(Schedulers.io()); // doing this to simulate an
                                                                                       // operation on another
                                                                                       // thread
    }
}

private class Bucket {
    public Async async() {
        return new Async();
    }
}

private List<Event> events() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Event(1L), new Event(2L), new Event(3L));
}

private Bucket bucket = new Bucket();

@Test
public void observableTest() throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off

    List<Observable<Pair<Event, Map<Long, Model>>>> observables = new ArrayList<>(); 
    for (Event e : events()) {
        observables.add(
                bucket
                    .async()
                        .get(e)
                            .map(event -> {
                                System.out.println("Thread: [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] - received event response, converting to map");
                                Map<Long, Model> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put(event.id, event.model);
                                return map;
                            })
                            .map(map -> {
                                System.out.println("Thread: [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] - pairing response with event");
                                return Pair.of(e, map); 
                            })); 
    }

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Map<Event, Map<Long, Model>> events = new HashMap<>();
    Observable
        .merge(observables)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .filter(pair -> {
                System.out.println("Thread: [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] - filtering responses");
                return pair.getValue() != null;   
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .subscribe(pair -> {
                               System.out.println("Thread: [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] - inserting response into map");
                               events.put(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
                           }, 
                           e -> {
                               fail();
                           },
                           () -> {                                   
                               latch.countDown();
                           });
    //@formatter:on

    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Thread: [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] - map count");
    assertEquals(3, events.size());
}
```

There are lots of gotchas with multithreaded RxJava (as in it doesnt always do what you expect) - here is a good article on understanding how it works: http://www.grahamlea.com/2014/07/rxjava-threading-examples/